# Importing pre-existing sqlite file and core data models with .xcdatamodel into newly created Swift application

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, swift

Currently i am importing pre-existing sqlite file and core data models with .xcdatamodel into newly created Swift Application. It has two tables say A & B. Whenever i try to access A table rows. Its giving me the following error.

> "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"

When i searched for this error i found some solutions which i applied but did not work. Solutions already applied are :

1. Delete the application & install again.
2. Reset the entire simulator and run again.
3. I even restarted Xcode which to me is stupid. But still did not work.

Here is my code :

```
var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url : NSURL!  = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("db", withExtension: "sqlite")
        println("Url :: \(url)")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        var options = NSMutableDictionary()
        options[NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption] = true
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
```

Can somebody help me out in this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you create NSManagedObjectModel ?

Comment: lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Inventory", withExtension: "mom")! //was momd
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }()

Comment: Is this db.sqlite file pre-existing sqlite file ?

Comment: Yes it is pre-existing sqlite file with all the data.

Comment: Core Data manages its own sqlite file. You can't give a sqlite file to core data and say you are storing all the data in this file. You have to manually move your pre-existing data from sqlite file to core data.

Comment: And how one could do that? I guess according to this link we can map pre-existing sqlite to core data :  http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Comment: Yes It is the solution

Comment: @AmeyGadre the question is about swift you ansered for objective-c, please answer for swift because i also need the answer